# $stateParams is not define

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm starting with ionic and i have encounter the following issue.
my $stateParams is returning an empty value whenever i'm trying to get the id of a specific place.

this is my controllers.js code for both my places and particular place:

```
.controller('PlacesCtrl', function($scope, NearbyPlaces){
        $scope.places = NearbyPlaces.all();
    })
.controller('PlaceCtrl', function ($scope,NearbyPlaces,$stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams.id);
        $scope.place = NearbyPlaces.get($stateParams.id);
    });
```

And this my services.js code:

```
.factory('NearbyPlaces', function() {
    var places = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Ben Sparrow',
        description: 'You on your way?',
        picture: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/P1150548_Paris_XIV_place_Denfert-Rochereau_rwk.jpg'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Max Lynx',
        description: 'Hey, it\'s me',
        picture: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/P1150548_Paris_XIV_place_Denfert-Rochereau_rwk.jpg15/08/2016'
    }];
    return {

        all: function() {
            return places;
        },
        get: function(placeId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
                if (places[i].id === parseInt(placeId)) {
                    return places[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

And my apps.js code:

```
   .state('app.places',{
        url:'/places',
        views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl: 'views/places.html',
                controller: 'PlacesCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.place-details',{
        url:'/places/:placeId',
        views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl:'views/place.html',
                controller:'PlaceCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead `$stateParams.id` you should use `$stateParams.placeId`.

More about `$stateParams` [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).